# how to get hard disk Serial Number using php on server side

Tags: php, mysqli, echo

The below I am mentioned my coding while am trying to get Hard Disk Serial Number. But I am getting error command on server side

My Code is :

```
$serial =  shell_exec('wmic DISKDRIVE GET SerialNumber 2>&1');

echo  $serial;
```

localhost Result : `SerialNumber 202020202020202020202020365a4445334*****`

BUT Server Result :

> sh: wmic: command not found

kindly revert me as Correct Solution.

Comment: maybe `shell_exec` has been disabled on the server for security reasons.

Comment: `wmic` maybe not install on your requested server or maybe there is a permission problem. see this http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php#106250

Comment: ok..i will refer your link now.

Answer (score -1):

```
   function GetVolumeLabel($drive) {
   if (preg_match('#Volume Serial Number is (.*)\n#i', 
   shell_exec('dir '.$drive.':'), $m)) {
   $volname = ' ('.$m[1].')';
   } else {
   $volname = '';
   }
   return $volname;
   }
   $serial = str_replace("
   (","",str_replace(")","",GetVolumeLabel("c")));

   echo $serial;
```

Comment: hi.. sir .. the above coding  shows on server  result  is empty view

Comment: any possible action .. permissions . or code changes ??